# How to programmatically rotate the screen in Gnome 3.28 (Wayland)?

Tags: gnome, wayland

I know how to rotate the screen in Xorg using `xrandr` or in Wayland using the `gnome-control-center` GUI, but is there a way to do it in Wayland using a command line interface or an API call ?

*Context*: I have a convertible laptop which is not supported by `iio-sensor-proxy`, and I would like to use a script or shortcut to quickly rotate the screen. Going back to Xorg is not an option.

Answer (score 7):

A partial solution is to set the `rotate-monitor` key to some keybinding using `gsettings` or `dconf-editor`.

For instance, the following command will cause `Ctrl+F8` to rotate the screen counterclockwise:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.mutter.keybindings rotate-monitor "['XF86RotateWindows', '<Control>F8']"
```

This does not allow the user to specify the target orientation, but only to rotate the screen until the desired orientation is reached.

Comment: This works for me on Fedora in 2021! THanks!

Comment: This will rotate the main notebook screen only. Is there away to specify which screen to rotate?